# Compatability between Windows Vista and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

I am wondering if anyone else is experiencing these same issues:

My main dev machine is a Dell, running Vista Home Premium and Visual Studio 2008 - both fully patched / up-to-date.

There are some quirks, such as the play/pause media controls on my keyboard not working while running Visual Studio 2008. These kinds of quirks are annoying, but not really problematic.

A bigger issue is this one:

In one of my solutions, I make use of a class called `Utility`. If I edit the class to add another field, no matter how many times I recompile/clean/manually delete the old `.DLL` files, the compiler tells me that there is no such field. If, however, I check the solution into SVN and then check it out on my laptop, which runs Windows XP SP3 with a fully patched Visual Studio 2008 - everything works fine. No idea why.

Has anyone else experienced this, or other problems with this kind of configuration? And if so, do you have any suggestions for how to overcome them?

Answer (score 1):

VS2008 runs fine on my Vista. All service packs (both VS & Vista) are installed.

I'm also using a MS keyboard: [Laser Desktop 4000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=094&active_tab=overview).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing things in elevated privileges mode? including reinstalling and all...

Answer (score 0):

I think its VS2008 I am having all sorts of wierd things happen with it but im running xp. Not to the degree that you say where it is messing with volume controls. My wierd things are in VS2008. For example I place a gridview on page 1 go to page 2 then back to page 1 and my gridview will have moved.. Its just buggy.. really buggy

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any performance profiling, vs is v naughty and puts instrumented dlls etc, in your VS IDE folder. You will then get references only to the instrumented version, not your newly updated DLLs (This keeps happening to me and I forget everytime to clear out the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE folder)